# Get specific XML row with PHP

Tags: php, xml, tags

I have this XML (example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<batch xmlns="http://www.polopoly.com/polopoly/cm/xmlio">
    <content clear="true">
        <metadata>
          <contentid>
            <major>Article</major>
            <externalid>m2021.article.1.39971373</externalid>

          </contentid>
          <input-template>
            <major>InputTemplate</major>
            <externalid>gele.FNtestxxx.StandardArticle2014v1</externalid>
          </input-template>
          <security-parent>
            <major>Department</major>
            <externalid>il-testatat.2014v1.versilia.cronaca.page</externalid>
          </security-parent>
          <workflowactions>
            <action>approve</action>
          </workflowactions>
        </metadata>
        <component name="name" group="polopoly.Content"><![CDATA[Il carro di Viani per il Carnevale 1911 e la “fake news” della tromba marina ]]></component>
        <component group="migrated" name="value">true</component>
        [...]
    </content>
    
    <content clear="true">
        <metadata>
          <contentid>
            <major>Article</major>
            <externalid>m2021.article.1.445685</externalid>
            [...]
```

I need to get the content of < component name = "name" group = "polopoly.Content" > and others.
My PHP code is this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach ($xml->content as $content) {
    $id = $content->metadata->contentid->externalid;
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $id, $matchesId);
    $id = $matchesId[0];
    
    $title = (string)$content->component['name'];
    
     $item = [
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => $title,
    ];
}
```

What's the right approach?
How can I get the single row with the specific attributes to the tags?
I need to loop the items and take the necessary fields.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use XPath, this allows you to search the XML as a structure and return specific elements using tags and attributes as criteria.

Answer (score 0):

This will get the `content` of the `<component>` element. I iterate over each `<content>` element and then iterate over each `<component>` element within it. With a check if the current `<component>` has the attributes `(name="name" and group="polopoly.Content")` and a match, extract the content of that element and assign it to `$title`.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($path);
foreach ($xml->content as $content) {
    $id = $content->metadata->contentid->externalid;
    preg_match('/\d+$/', $id, $matchesId);
    $id = $matchesId[0];

    $title = null;
    foreach ($content->component as $component) {
        if ($component['name'] == 'name' && $component['group'] == 'polopoly.Content') {
            $title = (string) $component;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    $item = [
        'id' => $id,
        'title' => $title,
    ];

    // Do something with $item
}
```